# NumPy doesn't recognize well array shape

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a code which is as follows:

```
data = np.array([[[i, j], i * j] for i in range(10) for j in range(10)])
print(data)

x = np.array(data[:,0])
x1 = x[:,0]
x2 = x[:,1]
print(x)
```

`data` correctly outputs `[[[0,0],0],[[0,1],0],[[0,2],0],...,[[9,9],81]]` which is, by the way, the multiplication table and it's results.

So, the first column of the `data` (which is `x`) must be separated into `x1` and `x2`, which are the first and last column of it respectively. Which I think I did it right but it raises an error saying `too many indices for array`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `np.array(data[:,0])` doesn't change the dtype (stays as object of 1D array). To fix : `np.vstack(data[:,0])` could be used.

Comment: The error says so because in the line `x1 = x[:,0]` you call an index for an axis that does not exist as you can see when calling `x.shape` (this gives `(100,)`). Also you see when calling `x` that `dtype=object`. I guess those are the two things you expected differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.dtype` is `object` because the elements of `[[i,j],k]` are not homogeneous.  A workaround for you :

```
data = np.array([(i, j, i * j) for i in range(10) for j in range(10)])
print(data)

x1 = data[:,:2]
x2 = data[:,2]
```

`data.shape` is now `(100,3)`, `data.dtype` is `int` and `x1` and `x2` what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the mix of list lengths, this produces an object array:

```
In [97]: data = np.array([[[i, j], i * j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)])
In [98]: data
Out[98]: 
array([[[0, 0], 0],
       [[0, 1], 0],
       [[0, 2], 0],
       [[1, 0], 0],
       [[1, 1], 1],
       [[1, 2], 2],
       [[2, 0], 0],
       [[2, 1], 2],
       [[2, 2], 4]], dtype=object)
In [99]: data.shape
Out[99]: (9, 2)
```

One column contains numbers (but is still object dtype), the other lists.  Both have (9,) shape

```
In [100]: data[:,1]
Out[100]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 4], dtype=object)
In [101]: data[:,0]
Out[101]: 
array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1],
       [2, 2]], dtype=object)
```

The easiest way of turning that column into a numeric arrays is via .tolist

```
In [104]: np.array(data[:,0].tolist())
Out[104]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
In [105]: _.shape
Out[105]: (9, 2)
```

The `[i, j, i * j]` elements as suggested in the other answer are easier to work with.

---

A structured array approach to generating such a 'table':

```
In [113]: dt='(2)int,int'
In [114]: data = np.array([([i, j], i * j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)],
     ...: dtype=dt)
In [115]: data
Out[115]: 
array([([0, 0], 0), ([0, 1], 0), ([0, 2], 0), ([1, 0], 0), ([1, 1], 1),
       ([1, 2], 2), ([2, 0], 0), ([2, 1], 2), ([2, 2], 4)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (2,)), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [116]: data['f0']
Out[116]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]])
In [117]: data['f1']
Out[117]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 4])
```